# Model Not Updating in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a custom select.i need to load the list once user clicks on the select

```
elem.bind('click',function(){
     scope.$apply(function(){
     scope.handler()();
     }):
});
```

This is calling the parent data bind method. It is being called with no problem.
But the model is not getting updated within my directive. I am using two-binding for my model. If i call the method from my parent controller. The model in my directive is getting without any issue. Am i missing anything?

Comment: Please share your directive and controller code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

As per details you have provided i can only suggest you that please make sure that you have given 'scope: false' while defining your directive.
which means directive will use the same scope object. This means any changes to the controller or directive will be in sync.

example -:

```js
app.directive("myDirective", function(){
  return {
    scope: false,
  }; 
});
```

that's it .... :)

Comment: Sorry for the little info. I am currently using isolated scope. There i have an object "Model" which is having two-way binding (=). My method currently updating the model in the parent controller properly. but it is not getting reflected in my directive.

Comment: So brother your problem is in your approach i.e if you are using isolated scope for directive then any change in controller scope will not be reflected in directive scope.
you can go to this link for more details about directives http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/
hope it will work.... :)

Comment: I got it resolved.. Actually i was using jquery in link function... That caused the issue. I changed it angular way now everything is great